# Cordova inappbrowser doesn't open in new webview on Android

Tags: android, cordova, webview, ionic-framework

I have a problem with [Cordova InAppBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) (within an ionic app, if this is relevant).

I try to open a new webview with a url (for authentication purposes). This should be a new webview, I need to get the `loadstart` event in my original cordova-webapp.

The following code works within iOS as expected, but on Android it seems to open the URL within the same webview (and not in a _blank, like specified). Do I miss something, or is this a bug?

```js
var browserRef = window.open(flatserverurl+'/tokenlogin?redirect=http://localhost/callback', '_blank', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
browserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
  // do something with the url
});
```

system info:

> - cordova 4.3.0
> - com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
> - cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
> - org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console" org.apache.cordova.device
> - 0.3.0 "Device"

tested it on Nexus 4 with Android 5.1.1 and two genymotion Android emulators (4.4.4 and 5.0.1)